# Firefox shortcuts opacity on new tab

Tags: windows-10, firefox

I want to change site shortcut opacity, excluding the site image in the shortcut.

I added background:transparent through inspect in div tile and it works, but if I try to put it in `userContent.css`, it doesn't work when I open Firefox on new page.

I already put a background image on new page with `usercontent.css`, but I don't know why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

```
.top-site-outer .tile {
    background:transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).